# Transpose a list based on specific text in ruby

Tags: ruby

I have one file which is one long list of different patient samples. Each sample  always starts with "SLX" as below:
I would like to transpose each sample into a CSV with the output shown below. I know that the CSV library might be able to do this but I don't know how to approach it as I would have to transpose only when the line starting with SLX is matched.

Input:

```
SLX.1767356.fdfsIH.fq.gz
Sequences: 160220
With index: 139019
Sufficient length: 139018
Min index: 0
Max index: 83
Unique: 48932
# reads processed: 48932
# reads with at least one reported alignment: 21172 (43.27%)
# reads that failed to align: 27022 (55.22%)
# reads with alignments suppressed due to -m: 738 (1.51%)
Reported 21172 alignments to 1 output stream(s)
SLX.94373.GHDUA_.fq.gz
Sequences: 28232
With index: 24875
Sufficient length: 24875
Min index: 3
Max index: 41
Unique: 14405
# reads processed: 14405
# reads with at least one reported alignment: 8307 (57.67%)
# reads that failed to align: 5776 (40.10%)
# reads with alignments suppressed due to -m: 322 (2.24%)
Reported 8307 alignments to 1 output stream(s)
SLX.73837.BLABLA_Control.fq.gz
Sequences: 248466
With index: 230037
Sufficient length: 230036
Min index: 0
Max index: 98
Unique: 64883
# reads processed: 64883
# reads with at least one reported alignment: 24307 (37.46%)
# reads that failed to align: 39764 (61.29%)
# reads with alignments suppressed due to -m: 812 (1.25%)
Reported 24307 alignments to 1 output stream(s)
```

Output

```
SLX.10456.FastSeqI_Control_OC_AH_094.fq.gz  Sequences: 160220   With index: 139019  Sufficient length: 139018   Min index: 0    Max index: 83   Unique: 48932   # reads processed: 48932    # reads with at least one reported alignment: 21172 (43.27%)    # reads that failed to align: 27022 (55.22%)    # reads with alignments suppressed due to -m: 738 (1.51%)   Reported 21172 alignments to 1 output stream(s) mv: /Volumes/SeagateBackupPlusDriv1/SequencingRawFiles/TumourOesophagealOCCAMS/MetaOCCAMSTumoursRawFiles/LCMDysplasiaAndCancer_LCM_PS14_1105_1F/SLX.10456.FastSeqI_Control_OC_AH_094.fq.gz and /Volumes/SeagateBackupPlusDriv1/SequencingRawFiles/TumourOesophagealOCCAMS/MetaOCCAMSTumoursRawFiles/LCMDysplasiaAndCancer_LCM_PS14_1105_1F/SLX.10456.FastSeqI_Control_OC_AH_094.fq.gz are identical
SLX.10456.FastSeqI_Control_OC_ED_008_F1_.fq.gz  Sequences: 28232    With index: 24875   Sufficient length: 24875    Min index: 3    Max index: 41   Unique: 14405   # reads processed: 14405    # reads with at least one reported alignment: 8307 (57.67%) # reads that failed to align: 5776 (40.10%) # reads with alignments suppressed due to -m: 322 (2.24%)   Reported 8307 alignments to 1 output stream(s)  
SLX.10456.FastSeqJ_OC_AH_086_F1_Control.fq.gz   Sequences: 248466   With index: 230037  Sufficient length: 230036   Min index: 0    Max index: 98   Unique: 64883   # reads processed: 64883    # reads with at least one reported alignment: 24307 (37.46%)    # reads that failed to align: 39764 (61.29%)    # reads with alignments suppressed due to -m: 812 (1.25%)   Reported 24307 alignments to 1 output stream(s)
```

Comment: The given desired output is not a valid CSV.

Comment: What is stopping you from writing a program to process the file?  In other words, what is your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, it’s so easy that I will post an answer.

```
input.scan(/^SLX.*?(?=^SLX|\z)/m)
     .map { |p| p.split($/).map { |e| %Q|"#{e}"| }.join (', ') }
     .join($/)
```